# How to achieve forward compatible string literals in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, literals

I've got a script which runs with python 3 except string literals.
Python 2.x force me to prefix string literals with u'' and python 3 dosen't understand it.
How to so solve that?

Comment: Wait for python 3.3 and use only `b''` or `u''` to denote strings. Otherwise you can use some (bad) tricks or the `2to3` script

Comment: 'denote strings'? what do You mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this when running it in python 2.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> s=['xx','yy','zz','aa']
>>> s
[u'xx', u'yy', u'zz', u'aa']
```

same thing when executed in python 3.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> s=['xx','yy','zz','aa']
>>> s
['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'aa']
```

Comment: This is for 2.6+. earlier 2.x's don't support `unicode_literals`

Comment: @gnibbler this satisfies me :), but nice to know

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

You can write all unicode strings as `u("a\u0020")`, using the following compatibility function. A similar trick can let you support `b('')` for bytes under Python 2.5. There is a small performance hit w/ the extra function call though. (This is what the [six](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/) 2/3 compatibility library uses).

```
if sys.version_info < (3,0):
    def u(s):
        return s.decode("unicode_escape")
else:
    def u(s):
        return s
```

Second, if you're not having to support Python 2.5, you can use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, and Python 2.6/2.7 strings for that module will behave the same as 3.x.

Finally, if you're not having to support Python 3.0-3.2, you can use `u''`, since Python 3.3 re-added support for the `u''` prefix due to popular pressure (mainly from webframework developers).

Answer (score 0):

You use a wrapper method, typically called `u`.

Here is my version (from [Porting to Python 3](http://python3porting.com/noconv.html), which you should read if you support both Python 2 and Python 3 with the same code.):

```
import sys
if sys.version < '3':
    import codecs
    def u(x):
        return codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x)[0]
else:
    def u(x):
        return x
```

You then use u('String') instead of u'String'. For non-ascii text you need to use the `\x00` , `\u0000` or `\N{name}` syntax.

Python 3.3 will support the u'' syntax again, to avoid this, but it's still in beta.

The `from __future__ import unicode_literas` feature has proven to be of little use, as you then need to instead have a wrapper to make native strings, which is not an improvement.